# Sabre Web/ .NET - Special Characters In SabreCommandLLSRQ Response Not Handed Properly

Tags: vb.net, soap, special-characters, sabre

I'm using VB.NET to consume Sabre Web Services, primarily using SabreCommandLLSRQ to send native Sabre commands. Sending special characters without any special encoding works fine, but when I try to manipulate any response that contain the Cross of Lorraine using the Response element of SabreCommandLLSRS all of the Cross of Lorraine chars are missing if I display my string in a MsgBox or try to manipulate it.

If I push that string into my clipboard and view it in Notepad++, the characters are there but they seem to be encoded improperly - they come through as something like "Â‡". I'm pretty new to unicode encoding so that's all a bit above my head.

I've tried using the Replace method of String Builder to change those characters to something visible no avail - anyone have a way around this issue?

Strangely, the other special characters (e.g. "¤") seem to come through just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This section in Dev Studio includes references to special character hex codes:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/utility/Send_Sabre_Command

Does this help?

Comment: That's somewhat helpful, but I'm strangely not having issues with sending the special chars, only receiving them. I don't know if VB.NET handles them differently than C# or what, but in my text responses, I'm getting the Â character plus something else that I can't decipher.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pain in the behind due to the invisible characters.

String replace does work you just need to make sure you capture the invisible character after the Â

Simply in the SabreCommandSend function before you send the string to Sabre put something like the below.

Hopefully this should copy and paste straight out including the invisible character.

```
  if (tempCommand.Contains("‡"))
                        {
                            tempCommand = tempCommand.Replace("‡", "Â");
                        }
```

Comment: Nope the invisible character can't be copied from the above. I believe I serialised the XML output to a string and pasted it into notepad, then if you highlight the Â and hold shift and click the right arrow and then ctrl-c you can copy the invisible character into a replace string.

Comment: Strangely, I can send the special characters just fine - it's reading them in the responses that I'm having an issue with. If I could figure out what the actual characters are to replace I'm thinking that it might work but I can't figure out what the 2nd character is after the Â.

Since I'm using the raw text response and not the XML I just can't seem to figure out how to capture and replace that particular character.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get this to work, but its not pretty so if anyone has a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

I couldn't figure out what char to use to do the simple string Replace method, so instead I'm casting the string to a byte array, iterating through the array and replacing any strange characters I find, recasting the byte array into a raw string and doing the string replace on that:

```
    Imports System.Text 
Dim byteArray() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sabreResponse)
        For i = 0 To byteArray.Length - 1
            If byteArray(i) = 63 Then 'this is a question mark char
                byteArray(i) = 94 'caret that doesn't exist in native Sabre
            End If
        Next
        MyClass.respString = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray)
        MyClass.respString = MyClass.respString.Replace("^", "¥")
```

For whatever reason, the string replace method works after I swap out the offending byte with a dummy character but not before.